# REST API to get the Role Instance Name based on Azure Instance Name that starts with RDxxxxx

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to get roleid rolename_0 or rolename_1 based on the Azure back end instance name that starts with RDxxxxxxx. I tried multiple APIs but all of them gives me only public IP, Private IP and my rolename_0 but from my data source I only have RDxxxxx name, which i need to convert to rolename_0 to do some automation. Any recommendations?

API I tried is the below one, the below API gives me all information of my cloud service and instance except the RDxxxxxx information

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroupname}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/{domainname}?$expand=deploymentSlots/roles/instances&api-version=2015-06-01